# How to update an openfire source(4.0.4) with multiple custom plugins made by us to later openfire source(4.3.2)

Tags: java, openfire

I have just started working on Openfire with no prior experience. We have a project which is an Openfire source. We have added multiple custom plugins which were created by us. My agenda is to keep the same functionality and update Openfire source version fro 4.0.4 to 4.3.2

As this is the source code of server I cannot upgrade it from single upgrade command.

The server version should be 4.3.2 with all the functionality i.e. all custom plugins.

Comment: Basic idea is to update dependencies to Openfire from your plugins (in build-system that you use: ant/maven/gradle etc.) and then rebuild the plugins.

Most probably migration 4.0.4 → 4.3.2 shouldn't cause very large compilation/execution problems, since it is a pretty minor version change.

If you have some problems when building with updated Openfire dependencies, post the concrete exceptions, build failure logs etc. Now the question is impossible to answer without having some particular problem/failure.

Comment: In 4.3 the Openfire is now on maven. While in 4.0.4 I used build.xml with ant to build plugin. can you explain how to build in maven? (As there is noo build.xml).

Comment: Wow, I didn't know that they switched to Maven in the new versions, but https://discourse.igniterealtime.org/t/pushing-openfire-over-the-maven-finish-line/81455 confirms it.

Super-basically, in maven you have `pom.xml` instead of `build.xml`.
To build, from command line, execute `mvn install` (assume you have maven installed and in `PATH`) from the directory with the root `pom.xml`.

I recommend you to read https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-lifecycle.html first, before asking about maven basics.

Let me know if there will be some problems with OF build.